# store data of a form into session and create a link

Tags: php, html

I have 2 pages in php. The 1st page includes a search form. All the results of this form I want to save them into a session. In the 2nd page I want a link so that if in search form someone types something, by clicking a link in the 2nd page to execute it. This is what I have done so far:

1st page

```
<form method="POST" name="go" action="search_form_all.php"  >
<input name="value" type="text" id="search_form_1" size="65"  autocomplete="off" placeholder=" Search People ..." style="" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" style="background:url('img/arrow.png') no-repeat; width:23px; height:23px; cursor:pointer; border:none; "/>
</form> 


<?php 
    // starting the session
session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
   $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];
} 
?>
```

2nd page

```
<?php  
  echo"<a href='search_form_all.php'>click to view results"; 
?>
```

Comment: so what is you problem??

Comment: I don't know if I did it correct with the session, the problem is that the link is not working...

Comment: echo"<a href='search_form_all.php'>click to view results</a>"; you forget to close the anchor tag

Comment: You've set the value in the session, but you never do anything with it? Do you need to echo it somewhere, or pass it to something else for processing?

Comment: any idea how to do this in order to call it in my link? All I want is that when I click on the link to execute the form, like pressing a submit button

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the name on your first page, but you're form's action is on 
*search_form_all.php*.
 Make sure that you are doing this

```
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];
```

in that page. Otherwise, there is no data to insert into your SESSION variable.

If you want you're form to be on the same page with

```
$_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];
```

you should use

```
<form method="POST" name="go" action=""  >
```

Also, I don't know if that's a problem, but I usually use **session_start()** on top of my page to be sure there aren't other headers before.

Hope it helps!